# Marshal/unMarshal reflect.Type

Tags: go

I created map[string]interface{} and i want to pass multiple types through the map between 2 reset services.

every time i marshal i get empty map in the field that should contain reflect.Type.

```
ServiceType:map[]
```

is it even possible?

code for testing: (the KeyValuePair will represent a single value of the map) and the MessageService can be replaced with any type of course

```
data := GenericHandlers.KeyValuePair{Key:"ServiceType",Value:reflect.TypeOf(MessageService.MessageService{})}
Json , _ := json.Marshal(data)
resKvp := GenericHandlers.KeyValuePair{}
err := json.Unmarshal(Json,&resKvp)
if(err != nil){
     log.Println(err.Error())
}
fmt.Println(resKvp)


type KeyValuePair struct{
        Key string
        Value interface{}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No, it's not possible.

Slightly longer answer: Since [relfect.Type](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf), as returned by `TypeOf`, is an *interface type* implemented by the **unexported** type [rtype](https://golang.org/src/reflect/type.go?s=#L292), none of whose fields are exported and whose method set does not contain the `MarshalJSON/UnmarshalJSON` methods, you cannot marshal or unmarshal a `reflect.Type` value as is.